# jquery validate for non disabled items

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has some inputs which are sometimes disabled (meaning, if the user answers certain questions, new input boxes will then become enabled.) I am trying to create a jquery code that will check for all of the non-disabled entrys from being blank. At the moment, I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('submit').click(function()
    {
        if( $(':text:not(:disabled)').val().length === 0) 
        {
            $('#message').html('All Entries Must Be Completed');

        }
    });                                     
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a preexisting jQuery validation plugin. Don't reinvent the wheel here. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: +1 to the above; the jQuery validation plugin is excellent.

Comment: +1 to @Matt; I agree with El Yobo - the jQuery .validate() plugin is excellent! All you do is set regular HTML attributes and call the plugin on a form element and it vlaidates everything. Add a class of `required` to make it required, add a class of `email` to make sure its a real email, etc. It's a very neat plugin. It's a plugin everyone should use for validation.

Comment: Even though I answered with a solution, I agree with these guys. If you are doing anything more with validation than you should definitely look at the validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Since this line:

```
$(':text:not(:disabled)')
```

Will return multiple items (an Array) you would need to loop over each one and check to see if it is empty using .val().

Or modify your selector to get only those that are disabled AND empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
            if( $(":text:not(:disabled)[value='']").length != 0) {
                    alert('All Entries Must Be Completed');
                    return false;
            }
    });                                     
});
```

Comment: No. I am getting back an array of any :text elements that are not disabled and do not contain any value. I am doing the value check in the selector. It's the [value=''] part.

Comment: ok, I understand. But I tried this and it did enter the if statement, but it does it even if my inputs are not blank. Why would this be?... Shouldn't there still be a .each statement since we are selecting mulitple values? Would this be the issue?...

Comment: And its supposed to be !==, not !=

Comment: forget about what I said, it works now... but I'm still not clear about why it doesn't need an .each. When do you need to loop and when not? We're always talking about multiple values...

Comment: You would only need to do an .each() if you were getting ALL of the :text values that were not disabled whether they had values or not. You would need to loop over each to see if they had values. Then show the message is any of them did not. The selector I suggested ONLY gets the :text elements that are disabled that don't have a value. So if the array has any elements in it at all then that means there was a non-disabled text with no value. So we only need ot check if there are any items in the array at all.